# How to do crossvalidation on a two-part regression model?

Tags: r, model, regression, logistic-regression

I am currently working on regression analysis to `model EQ-5D-5L` health data. This data is inflated at the upper bound i.e. 1, and one of the approaches I use to model is with two-part models. By doing that, I combine a `logistic model` with binary data (*1 or not 1*), and continuous data.

The issue comes when trying to **cross-validate** (*K-fold*) the two-part models: I cannot find a way to include both "parts" of the model in the caret package in `R`, and I have not been able to find anybody that has solved the problem for me.

When I generate the  predictions from the two-part model, it is essentially the coefficients from the two separate models that are multiplied together. So the models are developed separately, as they model different things from the same variable (binary and continuous outcome), but joined together when used to predict values.

Could it be possible to somehow **cross-validate** each part of the model separately, and get some kind of useful answer out of it?

Hope you guys can help.